# How to input a whole paragraph from the user in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am making a Diary app using android studio in which the user can enter as many paragraphs as he wants. And what he enters will be saved using a database. It is sort of like notepad- hence my UI has to be a blank page in which the user can start typing from the top. Also if the page becomes full, the cursor should automatically switch to the next blank page. I don't think I can use an EditText here as the EditText will have to fit the entire screen. Is there some other feature in android using which a whole paragraph can be input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sounds like you want your EditText View to take up the full parent or `FILL_PARENT` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html check this out. In the future please post your XML and what you have tried so far!